# SQL Server 2008 R2 Transactions Files

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, transaction-log

Trying to restore a lost Server 2008 database. Had a backup from 2 weeks ago and were able to get the transaction log files. So I restored the DB in norecovery mode and started restoring the transactions log files since the full backup time. There are a couple of files for each day so I have a lot of files to apply and everything seems to going good except for one question. I have gone through a couple of transaction files but do not see the file size of the DB increasing? So I am worried the transactions files are not being applied. Is there another way to check if transaction log data is being recovered? I know I can't bring the DB online till I finish through all the transaction log files.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data file doesn't have to grow to incorporate the transaction log entries. It may do on later restores of course

The transactions *are* being applied if the restore is successful: and if the next one works too. And you have restored 2 which means the 1st was OK

The backup files have some internal information (LSN) that are compared on restore to the LSN of the database. They must match and you can't skip a restore. Based on this, you have confidence that previous restores are OK

Comment: Yes I figured that when I got to the 40th transaction log and it was corrupt. So I had to restart the restore process.